# Windows Start Command Opening A Blank Prompt

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I am trying to get one command prompt to open another.  Here is the whole program:

```
@echo off
prompt $g

echo Loading Saved Game...
cls
start /B /D "%cd%\game\playsave.bat"
::playsave starts in this window, do
::not write any additional lines below
```

Whenever I run this, it displays the starter text (the Microsoft Windows Copyright) instead of playsave.bat

Why might this be happening, and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

There's two problems, the first is that you didn't supply a directory for the `/D` option, which specifies the current directory that the command will use. The other problem is the quotes you put around the name of the command. The `start` command interprets quotes in the first argument as the title to give to the new window. To get around this provide an empty title as the first argument. So you want something like:

```
start /B /D "%cd%\game" "" "%cd%\game\playsave.bat"
```

Comment: Something strange happened at first.  A second prompt opened, with no text, and the original one still had the copyright text.  After that, I tried running it again and I just had the same problem as before.  Anything else I could try?

Comment: @Jomundw I've updated my answer.  I hadn't noticed that the `/D` option was missing an argument